# How to read and write to a Paradox 7.x database from .NET app?

Tags: c#, .net, database, paradox

I develop .NET application (C#) and I need to read and update some data in a Paradox 7.x database.

According to [Microsoft article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/230126/how-to-use-paradox-data-with-access-and-jet) for Paradox 7-8 no support is provided for OLEDB.

According to [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/557811/is-it-possible-to-read-to-a-paradox-7-x-db-file-in-a-net-app) reading is possible, but not writing.

So is there any approach (maybe some third-party library or some BDE wrapper) how can I read and write to Paradox 7.x database?

**UPDATE** I've tried OleDB approach:

```
var builder = new OleDbConnectionStringBuilder();
builder.DataSource = "D:\\MyBase\\";
builder.Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0";
var connection = new OleDbConnection(builder.ToString() + ";Extended Properties=Paradox 5.x");
var command = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM Planes", connection);

connection.Open();
using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
     if (reader.HasRows)
         while (reader.Read())
               listBox1.Items.Add(reader.GetString(2));
```

This one fails with OleDbException (expectable because my database has Paradox 7.x format):

> External table is not in the expected format

If I change connecton string to `Extended Properties=Paradox 7.x` -
that one fails with enother OleDbException (expectable because Paradox 7 is not supported by OLEDB according to Microsoft article))

> Invalid operation

I've tried ODBC approach:

```
var connectionString = "Driver={Microsoft Paradox Driver (*.db )};" 
                + "DriverID=538;Fil=Paradox 7.X;"
                + "DefaultDir=D:\\MyBase\\;"
                + "Dbq=D:\\MyBase\\;"
                + "CollatingSequence=ASCII;";

var connection = new OdbcConnection(connectionString);
var command = new OdbcCommand("SELECT * FROM Planes", connection);

connection.Open();
using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
      if (reader.HasRows)
            while (reader.Read())
                  listBox1.Items.Add(reader.GetString(2));
```

That one also fails with OdbcException

> ERROR [HY000] [Microsoft] [Paradox ODBC driver] External table is not in the expected format

So nothing work nor now..

Comment: See if any of this helps: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/452c134f-cb37-4b12-88ad-ef18b877433f/paradox-7-reading-in-c?forum=csharpgeneral

Comment: @PeterB I've tried all approaches - see **UPDATE** section

Comment: Then maybe this: https://www.connectionstrings.com/paradox/

Comment: @PeterB Tried from both **.NET Framework Data Provider for OLE DB** and **Microsoft Paradox Driver** sections - still same errors..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So finally I managed read and **even write** Paradox 7.x database via **Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0** (decpite of [Microsoft tells](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/230126/how-to-use-paradox-data-with-access-and-jet) us that Paradox 7-8 is not supported):

1. Install [AccessDatabaseEngine for Office 2007 (32bit)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23734)
2. Install [AccessDatabaseEngine for Office 2010 (32bit)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255) (choose **AccessDatabaseEngine.exe**)
3. Install BDE 5.1.1.1 (It's better to install somewhere like D:\BDE)
4. Via BDE Administrator [change NET DIR](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/b31f8ed5-7f53-4d1d-901f-93f1dd5e13ae/windows-7-error-unexpected-error-from-external-database-driver-11265?forum=officesetupdeploylegacy) from C:\ to any folder, where you have write privileges (I've changed to D:\BDE)

After following code works like a charm

```
var builder = new OleDbConnectionStringBuilder();
builder.Add("Provider", "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0");
builder.Add("Data Source", @"D:\MyBase\");
builder.Add("Persist Security Info", "False");
builder.Add("Extended properties", "Paradox 7.x; HDR=YES");
var connection = new OleDbConnection(builder.Tostring()); 
var command = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM Planes", connection);
//reading
connection.Open();
using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
     if (reader.HasRows)
         while (reader.Read())
               listBox1.Items.Add(reader.GetString(2));
//writing
command = new OleDbCommand("DELETE * FROM Planes", connection);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
connection.Close();
```

Hope this information will help somebody like me.

Comment: Are Microsoft Access Database Engine 2007 and 2010 really needed here? I have BDE 5.1.1.1 and I can select data, but I have errors when trying to write to Paradox database: "Operation must use an updateable query" for insert, "Syntax error in UPDATE statement" for update, and "Could not delete from specified tables" for delete.

Comment: @meir Well, it was 2.5 years ago :) You can follow my guide, as far as I remember I was able to write data.

Comment: As someone who did this in 2023 - installing Access Engine for 2007 is no longer an option. Finding Borland Database Engine (including SQL Links) is what did the trick for me + Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable. Without the BDE setup it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

So here's what it takes to get Paradox running in 2023, because Access Engine for 2007 is no longer available (and most likely the 2010 one will soon be gone, so save your setup files somewhere if you will have to deal with paradox databases in the future):

1. Download and install Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable
2. Borland Database Engine (including SQL Links) - not sure if SQL links are needed - this is what I used.

The connection string below successfully connects to the paradox table

```
        public string PXcstr {
            get {
                return
                    @"DRIVER=Microsoft Paradox Driver (*.db );UID=admin;UserCommitSync=Yes;Threads=3;SafeTransactions=0;ParadoxUserName=admin;ParadoxNetStyle=4.x;" +
                    @"ParadoxNetPath=" + NetDir + ";PageTimeout=5;MaxScanRows=800;MaxBufferSize=20480;FIL=Paradox 7.X;DriverId=538;" +
                    @"DefaultDir=" + ParadoxDB + ";DBQ=" + ParadoxDB + ";CollatingSequence=International";
            }
        }
```

NetDir and ParadoxDB are both the same and point to the directory where my .db file is stored. It may be important to say that my console application is the only user accessing them, no other network users are connecting to this, so proceed with caution about that.

Update:

As asked how to use it - here's a copy of a code running in production:

```cs
            using ( var PXdb = new OdbcConnection( cfg.PXcstr ) ) {
                PXdb.Open();
                try {
                    using ( var PXcmd = new OdbcCommand( "select * from Sales", PXdb ) ) {
                        using ( var PXdr = PXcmd.ExecuteReader() ) {
                            var table = new DataTable();
                            table.BeginLoadData();
                            table.Load( PXdr );
                            table.EndLoadData();
                            // do stuff
                        }
                    }
                } finally {
                    PXdb.Close();
                }
            }
```

Comment: Can you please add example code utilizing this connection string? What provider are you using? What connection class are you using? Etc.

Comment: Edited my answer - see above